# VertX3 verticle deployment: CompletionHandler not triggered

Tags: java, vert.x

When I run the following piece of code:

```
import io.vertx.core.*;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.MessageConsumer;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class TestVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestVerticle.class.getName());

    public static final String ADDRESS = "oot.test";

    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
        logger.info("starting test verticle");
        MessageConsumer<JsonObject> consumer = vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESS);
        consumer.handler(message -> {
            final JsonObject body = message.body();
            logger.info("received: " + body);
            JsonObject replyMessage = body.copy();
            replyMessage.put("status", "processed");
            message.reply(replyMessage);
        });
        logger.info("started test verticle");
    }
}
public class Scratchpad {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scratchpad.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        logger.info("deploying test verticle");
        Handler<AsyncResult<String>> completionHandler = result -> {
            System.out.println("done");
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                logger.info("deployment result: " + result.result());
            } else {
                logger.error("failed to deploy: " + result);
            }
        };
        TestVerticle testVerticle = new TestVerticle();
        vertx.deployVerticle(testVerticle, completionHandler);

        logger.info("deployment completed");
    }
}
```

I expect the CompletionHandler content to be executed and therefore I should get something sent to stdout (at least "done", although the logging should be working as well) but nothing happens. All the other logging information shows up correctly on my screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After:

```
logger.info("started test verticle");
```

Add:

```
startFuture.complete();
```

See [Asynchronous Verticle start and stop](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_asynchronous_verticle_start_and_stop) section of the docs about the *asynchronous start method*:

> This version of the method takes a Future as a parameter. When the method returns the verticle will not be considered deployed.
>
> Some time later, after you've done everything you need to do (e.g. start other verticles), you can call complete on the Future (or fail) to signal that you're done.